# how to debug ipc programs

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, ipc, semaphore

I am facing a strange and unpredictable situation in my semaphore code. The following code has 3 processes - 1 master, 2 slaves - and all 3 expected to operate in lock-step manner using 2 "start" semaphores and 2 "done" semaphores. The master uses sem_start[i] to initiate the 2 slaves, and each of them signal their completeion to master using sem_done[i]. This loop goes on forever, until user enters the number 0. **This code works as expected.**

But now I wanted to do some initialization before starting the master, so I added one more semaphore sem_top, with which to start the master function. And thats when the program started behaving crazily - sometimes the program suspends, sometimes some of the processes are terminated.

Then I commented out all the new code, and just kept the declaration and the sem_init lines (ie the sem_post and sem_wait lines for sem_top were still commented), and even then the program does NOT work.

So here I am - **added a new semaphore and initialized it, and did NOT use it, and the code stopped working**.

Any ideas on what can possibly be the cause of error, and how to debug such ipc problems? I am not seeing any error being reported. Am I allocating the shared memory improperly, or using the semaphores in undefined ways? (I am facing this problem on ubuntu20.)

To compile the program:

```
gcc -o master master.c -lpthread
gcc -o slave slave.c -lpthread
```

To run the lock-step processes:

```
1. ./master --> wait for the prompt, and start-msg from the 2 slaves
2. then: enter 1-9 to run each loop, 0 to quit
```

To witness the bug:

```
#define BUG 1
```

Here is the code:

```
// master.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_PROCS 2
#define BUG 0

typedef struct {
    sem_t sem_start[NUM_PROCS];
    sem_t sem_done[NUM_PROCS];
#if BUG
    sem_t sem_top;
#endif
    int cmd;
} sharedmem_t;

sharedmem_t *shmp;

void error(char *s) { printf("%s\n", s); exit(0); }

void *Top(void *t) {
    int loop_count = 0;

    printf("Top waiting to start:============\n");
    //if (sem_wait(&shmp->sem_top) == -1)
    //    error("sem_wait top");
    while(1) {
        printf("Enter 1-9 to start loop=%d, 0 to quit:============\n", loop_count);
        scanf("%d", &shmp->cmd);
        printf("Top initiating\n");
        for(int i=0; i<NUM_PROCS; i++) {
            if (sem_post(&shmp->sem_start[i]) == -1)
                error("sem_post start");
        }
        if(shmp->cmd==0) exit(0);
        loop_count++;
        printf("Top waiting-%d============\n", loop_count);
        for(int i=0; i<NUM_PROCS; i++) {
            if (sem_wait(&shmp->sem_done[i]) == -1)
                error("sem_wait done");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid0,pid1,pid2;
    pid_t rpid;
    int status;
    int shmid;
    key_t key=12345;

    char *args1[] = {"./slave", "S1", "0", NULL};
    char *args2[] = {"./slave", "S2", "1", NULL};

    shmid=shmget(key,sizeof(sharedmem_t),0666|IPC_CREAT);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    shmp=(sharedmem_t *)shmat(shmid,(void *)0,0);
    if (shmp == (sharedmem_t *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat:shmp");
        exit(1);
    }

#if BUG
    if (sem_init(&shmp->sem_top, 1, 0) == -1)
        error("sem_init top");
#endif
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PROCS; i++) {
        if (sem_init(&shmp->sem_start[i], 1, 0) == -1)
            error("sem_init start");
        if (sem_init(&shmp->sem_done[i], 1, 0) == -1)
            error("sem_init done");
    }

    if((pid0 = fork()) < 0) { printf("\n Fork failed!\n");  return 1; }
    if (pid0 == 0) { // child-0
        printf("Top scheduled with pid=%d\n", getpid());
        Top(NULL);
        sleep(1);
        exit(0);
    }

    if((pid1 = fork()) < 0) { printf("\n Fork failed!\n");  return 1; }
    if (pid1 == 0) { // child-1
        printf("%s scheduled with pid=%d\n", args1[1], getpid());
        execv("./slave", args1);
        sleep(1);
        exit(0);
    }
    if((pid2 = fork()) < 0) { printf("\n Fork failed!\n");  return 1; }
    if (pid2 == 0) { // child-2
        printf("%s scheduled with pid=%d\n", args2[1], getpid());
        execv("./slave", args2);
        sleep(1);
        exit(0);
    }

    // TBD.. do some initialization stuff here
    //   ...
    // now initiate Top:
    //if (sem_post(&shmp->sem_top) == -1)
    //    error("sem_post top");

    // now parent waits for all children to end
    while(1) {
        rpid=wait(&status);
        if(rpid<0) break;
        printf("Child %d returned\n",rpid);
        sleep(1);
    }

    printf("All children exited\n");
    if ((shmdt(shmp)) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
    } else {
        if ((shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL)) == -1) {
            perror("shmctl");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// slave.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_PROCS 2

typedef struct {
    sem_t sem_start[NUM_PROCS];
    sem_t sem_done[NUM_PROCS];
    int cmd;
} sharedmem_t;
sharedmem_t *shmp;

void error(char *s) { printf("%s\n", s); exit(0); }
char* name;
int semid;

void *proc(void *t) {
    int loop_count = 0;
    printf("starting slave-%s-%d\n", name, semid);
    while(1) {
        printf("%s waiting-%d============\n", name, loop_count);
        if (sem_wait(&shmp->sem_start[semid]) == -1)
            error("sem_wait start1");
        if(shmp->cmd==0) {
            printf("%s ending\n", name);
            exit(0);
        }
        sleep(1);
        printf("%s done\n", name);
        if (sem_post(&shmp->sem_done[semid]) == -1)
            error("sem_post done1");
        loop_count++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int shmid;
    key_t key=12345;

    name = argv[1];
    semid = atoi(argv[2]);

    shmid=shmget(key,sizeof(sharedmem_t),0666);
    if (shmid < 0) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }
    shmp=(sharedmem_t *)shmat(shmid,(void *)0,0);
    if (shmp == (sharedmem_t *)(-1)) {
        perror("shmat:shmp");
        exit(1);
    }

    proc(NULL);
    sleep(1);
    exit(0);

    printf("All children exited\n");
    if ((shmdt(shmp)) == -1) {
        perror("shmdt");
    } else {
        if ((shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL)) == -1) {
            perror("shmctl");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mixing POSIX semaphores and sysV semaphores/shared memory is probably not a great idea. Actually, *using* sysV semaphores/shared memory is a bad idea on its own already.

Comment: @EOF: I tried moving the semaphores outside the shm struct, but the program stops working. Let me know if you have a more constructive suggestion, than just saying mixing semaphore and shm is a bad idea.

Comment: There are several *sets* of Unix APIs available in current systems, roughly derived from AT&T's commercial "SystemV Unix", and from Berkeley's "BSD Unix". Even shared APIs like signals tend to have horrendous incompatibilities between these two ancestries. So, if you want to use APIs, you should check the relevant manpages to see which historical branch of Unix they come from, and *try* to stick to one of them only.

Comment: That is interesting, I had seen several blogs for code snippets, and nobody mentioned not to mix the 2 ways, in fact many of them give examples of mixed code. But what you say makes sense. My sem code is in posix, but my shm code is in sysv. Let me move the sem code also to sysv, and give it another try.